# rPy2 slice matrix

Tags: python, r, matrix, rpy2

I have this [matrix](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html?highlight=matrix#matrix) in `rPy2` in **Python 2.7**.

```
m = robjects.r.matrix(robjects.IntVector(range(15)), nrow=5)
print(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    5   10
[2,]    1    6   11
[3,]    2    7   12
[4,]    3    8   13
[5,]    4    9   14
```

I am trying extract 2 slices from this matrix. In the first slice (1. below) I need to extract all columns for a range of rows. In the second slice (2. below), I need to extract all rows for a range of columns.

1.

I need to extract all columns for rows 2-4:

```
[2,]    1    6   11
[3,]    2    7   12
[4,]    3    8   13
```

I tried this:

```
a = m.rx([2:5], True)
```

but it does not accept a Python list.

2.

I need to extract all the rows from columns 2,3:

```
     [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   10
[2,]    6   11
[3,]    7   12
[4,]    8   13
[5,]    9   14
```

Again, I do not know how to specify a list of columns:

```
b = m.rx(True, [2:4])
```

does not work.

How can I achieve these slices `a` and `b` of the matrix `m` in `rPy2`?

Comment: Can you convert to a data frame using as.data.frame() and then use your suggested sub-setting method?

Comment: I was hoping to just use the matrix since I would not be using a `data.frame()`. A matrix is sufficient for my requirements. Is it not possible to slice a matrix?

Comment: Yes, it does. Try `m <- as.matrix(m)` instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks. However, I am working in Python. So, I would like to slice the `rPy2` matrix in Python.

Comment: Doh! Sorry didn't read closely enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
b = m.rx(True, IntVector((2,3)))
```

Comment: Sigh! No, I did not try that. Great answer! Thanks.